# Was Obi-Wan Kenobi an alcoholic?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, obi-wan-kenobi, attack-of-the-clones

There are scenes in Star Wars that provide a certain subtext that suggests to me, that dear Old Ben may have had a drinking problem. Or, at the least, may have been a regular at the local bar.

First, in Attack of the Clones (quote source [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0121765/quotes)):

> Anakin Skywalker: I think he's a she... and I think she's a Changeling.
>
> Obi-Wan Kenobi: In that case be extra careful. Go and find her.
>
> [He heads towards the bar]
>
> Anakin Skywalker: Where are you going, Master?
>
> Obi-Wan Kenobi: For a drink.

Obi-Wan then proceeds to comfortably get a (presumably hard) beverage and use a Jedi mind-trick to make a dealer go away as if he's done this several times before.

He also gets a drink in Dex's diner.

In A New Hope, Obi-Wan has a suspicious knowledge of Mos Eisley and the local scene there. In addition, the first thing he does is immediately go to the bar. Of course, he tells Luke that it's to find a pilot to take them to Alderaan, but who says you can't knock out two birds with one stone?

Now, much of the above is fairly tongue-in-cheek, but here is the primary question:

**Is there any canon evidence to suggest that Obi-Wan Kenobi may have had a drinking problem?**

You may give your answer from Disney Canon or from Legends Canon, but please specify which in your answer.

EDIT NOTE: This question has been changed. The original wording of the question was: "Is there **sufficient** canon evidence to suggest that Obi-Wan Kenobi may have had a drinking problem?" (emphasis on the changed word)

EDIT 2: Someone in the comments suggested that perhaps none of the beverages Obi-Wan drank may have been alcoholic and requested evidence that the drinks were indeed alcoholic. The answer to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140298/did-obi-wan-kenobi-ever-drink-alcohol/140556#140556) question confirms that at least one of them was.

Comment: You give examples of him drinking, but not of any problem.

Comment: You also failed to provide a proof that he orders (and drinks) alcoholic drinks. Check  for example "Back to the future III", where Doc often visits Saloon but never drinks alcohol.

Comment: @Blackwood The problem is pure speculation on my part (and I am not the first to wonder). The purpose of the question is to identify if there is any other canon evidence that could substantiate the speculation. I am fully prepared for that answer to be no.

Comment: @Yasskier My first thought was "for sure that's alcohol! That's got to be confirmed in canon **somewhere**!". Alas, all the googling in the world did not bring forth an answer from canon that any of the beverages that Obi-Wan ever orders are in fact alcoholic. Therefore, I am opening a new question to address this.

Comment: You ask for "sufficient" canon evidence. Is there **any** canon evidence? In *Star Wars*, we see the Larses and Luke drinking large quantities of a liquid that looks like blue milk. The amount they drink indicates a level of enjoyment that suggests "blue milk" is alcoholic. We also see Luke drinking a beverage in the Mos Eisley cantina. Is there sufficient evidence to suggest that Luke and the Larses are raging alcoholics, and in fact that the Larses were so pickled they spontaneously combusted before any imperials found them? Comment based on M-canon.

Comment: I'd say the scene with the changeling was more a trap he set, with himself as 'bait'. The changeling knew there were two Jedi on their trail, one goes to the bar to order a drink, while the other is sent around the bar to 'ruffle feathers'. It would seem to be easier to take them down separately, so the changeling deliberately targets the one they think is not being 'hyper vigilant' as Anakin was. But the force sense of Obi Wan was in no way dulled (to detect the approach from behind), nor was his skill with the light sabre (a single swipe to incapacitate, but not kill, the changeling).

Comment: @Todd Wilcox Fair enough, I realize my wording on the question sets an ambiguous boundary on what would be considered "sufficient". Any canon evidence will do. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Since this question has attracted such negative attention, I am open to critiques as to how I can improve the question.

Comment: People like you give alcoholics like me a bad name.

Comment: **Nursing a drink** is a time-honored tradition if you need/ant to be in a bar while not getting drunk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is **no canon evidence** to suggest that Obi-Wan has a "*drinking problem*". He does appear to consume alcoholic beverages on several occasions (in the Outlander Club and Dex's Diner in AotC, for example) but in each case he only appears to have a single drink and evidently does not become intoxicated, nor do we see him engaged in 'drink-seeking' behaviour in any of the films, comics, books or other canon properties.

You may also wish to note that as a Jedi Master, alcoholism would be a very serious failing, one that would instantly disqualify one from any consideration as a member of the Jedi Council.

> *For those who have passed that test, **you will do well to remember that
> this [the third and final] pillar is Self-Discipline**, not Combat. It is impossible to wield
> a lightsaber **without first mastering the action of your physical
> self.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Jedi Path: A Manual for Students of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book))</sup></sub>

Comment: I agree with your answer, though if you could provide a source that specifically suggests that alcoholism to be a failing of a Jedi, then I will be more tempted to accept

Comment: @DBPriGuy I doubt there is a source that specifically states that, but it is something that can be inferred. Jedi are all about controlling their emotions and actions. An alcoholic is somebody who is failing to control themselves.

Comment: @ncalmbeblpaicr0011 I'm not seeking a specific prohibition on alcohol, but merely a reference to the Jedi's value for Self-Discipline, which Valorum has just supplied. I will happily accept this answer.

Comment: For the record, I am extremely self-disciplined in my drinking. Every time I get blinding drunk, it was completely by my own choice :)