# Did Obi-Wan Kenobi ever drink alcohol?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, obi-wan-kenobi

On [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140297/was-obi-wan-kenobi-an-alcoholic) question, someone in the comments pointed out that while Obi-Wan Kenobi orders drinks at bars a couple times throughout the movies, there appears to be a lack of evidence that those drinks are alcoholic at all.

**Can it be confirmed whether or not Obi-Wan Kenobi has had an alcoholic beverage?**

You may give an answer from Disney Canon or Legends; please specify which in your answer.

Comment: No, never. </headcanon>

Comment: There isn't any direct evidence, but it's heavily implied. The direct quote from AotC is:

"Where are you going, Master?"  
"For a Drink."

Which suggests he's going to get himself an alcoholic beverage after a long day, a pretty common trope in a lot of movies.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo I agree. However, in the linked question, the commenter specifically required hard proof as opposed to implication. Between the two different canons I figured there should be hard evidence somewhere to prove one way or another.

Comment: Not alcohol, but there was also the incident where he accidentally ruptured some barrels containing certain "substances", and found disoriented and quite happy by Anakin. Along with the faint hint that Obi-Wan had previously drank something like "Whyren Reserve" if I recall, on Cato Neimoidia if I also recall, from the book Labyrinth of Evil if I further recall. I'm on a business trip and don't have access to my library, so can't pinpoint on the quote and dialogues.

Comment: There's no good evidence that he was drinking alcohol in the bar in AotC. His drink comes from a carbonator mixer, but it also serves "non-toxic" drinks.

Comment: @VerpinZal - "*Battle droids were still entering with each parting of the doors, and spores were still wafting through the air. Not much had changed, except within **Obi-Wan, who felt as if he had downed three bottles of Whyren’s Reserve. Bleary-eyed but lucid, tipsy but sure-footed, weary but attentive,** Obi-Wan seemed to be the sum of all contrasts."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Dex's diner (in *Attack of the Clones*) Obi-Wan drinks a beverage called "*Jawa Juice*", identified in the film's official novelisation as "[Ardees](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ardees)".

> With great effort, Dexter managed to squeeze himself into the seat opposite Obi-Wan. The waitress droid was back by then, **setting two steaming mugs of ardees in front of the old friends.**

We learn in the short story ["Born in the Storm"](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Born_in_the_Storm) that Jawa juice is alcoholic

> *So we geared up, rolled out, and there we were in the heart of Mos Eisley, getting crispy beneath all those layers of armor and this giant black bodysock, and quite frankly craving a thirst quencher, and **I don’t mean the kind that actually quenches thirst. I mean the kind that dehydrates, in fact. A beverage, specifically one that frizzles, to be precise. Jawa juice, in case I wasn’t clear. I wanted a damn drink.***

The fully canon *[Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know)* factbook also confirms that ardees contains fermented grains, indicating that it's an alcoholic beverage.

> [image: image of the relevant entry in the factbook, transcribed below]
>
> **2. DRINK**
>   **Thirsty? Bantha-blood fizz**
>   is a sparkling beverage
>   made from **purified bantha
>
>   blood!** Bantha hides can
>   also be **mashed** with
>   fermented grains to create
>   the bitter drink **Ardees**,
>   aka **"Jawa Juice"**.

Comment: Great find! I'd say if fermented grains cannot be interpreted as anything *other* than alcohol

Comment: Tofu is the curd from fermented beans and soymilk is a form of fermented bean, so there are non-alcoholic interpretations as well!

Comment: @bp. - And while that's true, I'm at a loss how you'd mash something with fermented ***grains*** and make a non-alcoholic drink other than by removing the alcohol chemically.

Comment: I thought it was against the Jedi Code to consume alcohol?

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - Where does it say that?

Comment: I must have confused that with another SC storyline I’m watching. I do know for a fact that it was frowned upon by the Council, especially during the Clone Wars. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Alcohol/Legends which makes sense. You are a Jedi during a war where your skills and mental focus with the Force needs to be sharp, and you go consuming a drink that unravels your focus.......I could see frowning. Lots of it. Especially on Padawans.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - Oh sure, Yoda probably tuts when Obi-Wan turns up for council meetings wearing shades and drinking an alka-seltzer but I don't believe it's banned by the code

Comment: And as his master would no doubt point out, The council frown on *lots of things* but that doesn't mean you have to agree with them